# Is my computer being controlled?

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently encountered a person on Skype that I don't know. I've heard about people being able to access your computer remotely. How can I tell if my computer has been compromised?

Comment: It is very common to have random people ask you for friend requests on Skype. I've had up to about 10 random people ask to be my friend. Some people will simply sift through account names and try and friend you. I'm pretty sure your mac is not compromised, but I don't have enough data to back me up, so I'm not trying to put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Applications like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) can be very useful for figuring out if your computer has been compromised, as they can detect incoming and outgoing connection attempts.

I would say that most likely the appearance of an unexpected person on Skype is just due to a spammer or scammer adding people at random from a list of names or email addresses. It's also possible that it's a case of mistaken identity, where the person on the other end is trying to contact someone with a similar name. Be wary of [social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) attempts, and do not open any links or attachments from this person!

If the person is bothering you or you're just weirded out, you can block the individual by right-clicking their contact portrait and choosing "Block *(name)*...".